# VWMA manual computation and TradingView Computation Don't Match

Tags: pine-script

According to the pine documentation:

```
pine_vwma(x, y) =>
    sma(x * volume, y) / sma(volume, y)
```

vwma1 and vwma2 should be equivalent, however, when I plot them, they are not equivalent values. What am I missing? This was taken from the Fibonacci Bollinger Bands script.

```
src = hlc3
top = sma(src*volume,15)
bot = sma(volume,15)

vwma1 = vwma(src,15)
vwma2 = top/bot
```

Here is the original script:

```
study(shorttitle="FBB", title="Fibonacci Bollinger Bands", overlay=true)
length = input(200, minval=1)
src = input(hlc3, title="Source")
mult = input(3.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50)
basis = vwma(src, length)
dev = mult * stdev(src, length)
upper_1= basis + (0.236*dev)
upper_2= basis + (0.382*dev)
upper_3= basis + (0.5*dev)
upper_4= basis + (0.618*dev)
upper_5= basis + (0.764*dev)
upper_6= basis + (1*dev)
lower_1= basis - (0.236*dev)
lower_2= basis - (0.382*dev)
lower_3= basis - (0.5*dev)
lower_4= basis - (0.618*dev)
lower_5= basis - (0.764*dev)
lower_6= basis - (1*dev)
plot(basis, color=fuchsia, linewidth=2)
p1 = plot(upper_1, color=white, linewidth=1, title="0.236")
p2 = plot(upper_2, color=white, linewidth=1, title="0.382")
p3 = plot(upper_3, color=white, linewidth=1, title="0.5")
p4 = plot(upper_4, color=white, linewidth=1, title="0.618")
p5 = plot(upper_5, color=white, linewidth=1, title="0.764")
p6 = plot(upper_6, color=red, linewidth=2, title="1")
p13 = plot(lower_1, color=white, linewidth=1, title="0.236")
p14 = plot(lower_2, color=white, linewidth=1, title="0.382")
p15 = plot(lower_3, color=white, linewidth=1, title="0.5")
p16 = plot(lower_4, color=white, linewidth=1, title="0.618")
p17 = plot(lower_5, color=white, linewidth=1, title="0.764")
p18 = plot(lower_6, color=green, linewidth=2, title="1")
```

Comment: I don’t know this tool, but it looks like you should be more specific about what result you’re getting vs. what result you want.

Comment: Which script are you referring to? "Be more specific" (c)